Cast a String of a DocumentReference, to a DocumentReference
I encoded a Firestore DocumentReference inside a json object. Then I embed this string in a QR code. Then read the QR code with "mobile_scanner" package
"subscriber_document_reference" : "${subscriber.subscriberDocumentReference}"

Once I decode it, I get map with String key and also a String value. I want to change  this String to an actual DocumentReference I can use.
naturally a direct cast fails with the exception:
 "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentReference<Object?>' in type cast"



Edit: This is the encoding
 final data = ' {"subscriber_document_reference": "${subscriber.subscriberDocumentReference}" }';

final payload = json.encode(data);

The subscriber.subscriberDocumentReference is the correct type here: DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>
I decode it
final String? displayValue = barcodes.barcodes.first.displayValue;  // mobile_scanner package code
final temp = json.decode(displayValue) as String;
final payload = json.decode(temp) as Map<String, dynamic>;

the value now is
"subscriber_document_reference": "DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>(......)

note: ignore the decoding twice. I don't know why it's doing that, but since it works, it works.

None. It's an abstract with no named constructors

I don't know how to do that. This is a Firestore Document Reference and extending requires implemnting 11 methods that manipulates the database. Even If I knew how to do that, I don't think it's advisable since it messes with database operations. I should have clarified in the post that it's a Firestore Document Reference.

Firestore? and why would you want to serialize the whole DocumentReference? it seems impossible, instead serialize just data it holds

I think you're absolutely right. Instead of encoding the entire DocumentReference, I should encode the document ID's in separate fields. Then reconstruct them back into a DocumentReference after the decoding.

Not sure what you are trying to do, but
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('nameOfYourCollection').doc('yourString')
should give a DocumentReference.
Or your error could be due to your DocumentReference is not converted to String, so where ever you decode, use toString() function.

Yes. It does give a DocumentReference. But when I encode into a String using a string interpolation "${subscriber.subscriberDocumentReference}", I decode it as a String as well. Now Since I cannot use this String in my Firestore calls. I need the DocumentReference it used to be.

what Firestore call are you making?

I found the answer with the help of @pskink. Instead of encoding the entire DocumentReference, I encoded the Document ID's that make up the DocumentReference. This works for me because the collection ID's are known and hardcoded.
Then I can reconstruct the DocumentReference with the usual Firestore syntax.
Firestore.instance.collection("my_collection_id").doc("decoded_id").collection("another_collection_id").doc("another_decoded_id")

